# cardinality of sigma algebra generated by a finite collections of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Let $\mathcal{B}=\{B_i: 1\le i\le k\}$, where $B_i\subset X$ for $1\le i\le k$. Find a surjection from $P(P(\{1,\ldots,k\}))$ to $\mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{B}$ and $P(A)$ is the set of subsets of $A$.

Can any one give me the hints for this problem ?

Comment: Try it out on the small cases $k=1$ and $k=2$ to get some ideas.

Comment: You can't prove that bijection exists unless you also assume that the $B_i$ are disjoint.

Comment: Sorry! I made a mistake. It must be a surbjection

Comment: You probably assume that $\mathcal B$ is a partition of $X$. Later on, the bijection is between $\mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,k\})$ and $\mathcal F$, not between $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\{1,\ldots,k\}))$ and $\mathcal F$.

Comment: $\mathcal{B}$ is not a partition of X

Comment: Well then it could be that $B_i=X$ for all $i$. In which case the sigma-algebra has only two elements.

Comment: Can you make it clear ?

Answer (score 2):

Small case $k=2$ to put you on track: let's say $\mathcal B=\{B_1,B_2\}$.

Then the sets $B_1\cap B_2$, $B_1\cap B_2^c$, $B_1^c\cap B_2$ and $B_1^c\cap B_2^c$ belong to $\mathcal B$, are disjoint and cover $X$.

Note that we are talking about at most $2^2=4$ *distinct* sets here.

The sets in $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ are exactly the sets that can be written as a union of these sets, this under allowance of the empty union.

That leads to the conclusion that there are at most $2^{2^2}=2^4=16$ *distinct* sets in $\sigma(\mathcal B)$.

---

**edit**:

E.g. sent set $\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{1,2\}\}\in\wp(\wp(\{1,2\}))$ to $(B_1^c\cap B_2^c)\cup(B_1\cap B_2^c)\cup(B_1\cap B_2)\in\mathcal B$.

Do you see the pattern?

---

**edit2**

Construction of surjection $f:\wp(\wp(\{1,\dots,k\}))\rightarrow\sigma(\mathcal B)$:

For $A\subseteq\left\{ 1,\dots,k\right\} $ let $f\left(\left\{ A\right\} \right):=R_{1}\cap\cdots\cap R_{k}$
where $R_{i}=B_{i}$ if $i\in A$ and $R_{i}=B_{i}^{c}$ otherwise.

Based on this define $f\left(\left\{ A_{1},\dots,A_{r}\right\} \right):=\bigcup_{i=1}^{r}f\left(\left\{ A_{i}\right\} \right)$
where $A_{1},\dots,A_{r}$ denote distinct subsets of $\left\{ 1,\dots,k\right\} $.

Comment: Thanks ! But the problem is that I am finding a map from $P(P(\{1,\ldots,k\}))$ to $\sigma(\mathcal{B})$ that is surjection

Comment: My answer points in the direction of $2^{2^k}$ elements at most for $\sigma(\mathcal B)$. Another notation for $\wp(\wp(\{1,\dots,k\}))$ is $2^{2^{\{1,\dots,k\}}}$. Doesn't that ring a bell?

Comment: Wait for me for a few minutes. I am thinking about your hints

Comment: I understood your point. But can we find the surjection specificly ?

Comment: See my edit for inspiration.

Comment: you mean that for each $I\subset P(\{1,\ldots,k\})$ we set $S_{I}=(\cap_{i\in I}B_i)\cap(\cap_{\{1,\ldots,k\}\backslash I}B_i^c)$, then we take the union of these things ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. See my edit2.

Comment: So we only need to prove that the collection $\cup_{i=1}^{r}f\left(\left\{ A_{i}\right\} \right)$ is a sigma algebra. Is it right ?

Comment: It is more like proving that the collection that I described in the first part of my answer (for special case $k=2$) is indeed the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal B$. That is enough. The function $f$ is a surjection to it. I am going to bed now. Good night.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will do it now