# What is the maximal number of elements in a sigma-algebra generated by A when A is a collection of N subsets of set X?

Tags: measure-theory

If A is a collection of N subsets of set X what is the maximal number of elements in a sigma-algebra generated by A?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433920/cardinality-of-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-finite-collections-of-sets .

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A=\left\{A_1,\dots,A_n\right\}$. Then the partition $S$ generated by $A$ consists of sets of the form
$$
A_1^{\xi_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_n^{\xi_n}
$$
where each $\xi_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ and by convention $A_i^0=A_i$ and $A_i^1=A_i^c$. $S$ consists of $2^n$ sets. The set of all possible unions of the sets in $S$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $A$. Hence it can contain at most $2^{2^n}$ sets. For each $n$ this bound can be attained as seen by the following example. Take 
$$
X=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i\in\{0,1\}\forall i\}.
$$
For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ define 
$$
A_i:=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in X:x_i=0\}.
$$
Define $A=\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$. The partition consists of all singletons of $X$ and the sigma-algebra generated by $A$ is the power set of $X$.

Comment: Right idea. Small things: $S$ not necessarily a *partition* since some of the intersections can be empty, and $S$ consists of *at most* $2^n$ sets (less is possible).

Comment: @Ramiro That's indeed what I meant to say. My "intersections" was not referring to intersections of elements of $S$ but to the sets $A_1^{\xi_1}\cap\cdots\cap A_n^{\xi_n}$ that are possibly empty. In that case $S$ is not really a partition.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you are right, some sets in $S$ may be empty.  For instance, if  $A_2=A_1^c$.