# Count number of subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

[image]
For this problem, I find it time-consuming to methodically go through writing down elements of each $S_i$ and check if there are any identical sets of apparently different expression. Are there any way to see this fast without doing much enumeration? Answer is (D) by the way.

Comment: The four sets $A \cap B$, $A \cap B^c$, $A^c \cap B$, and $A^c \cap B^c$ are pairwise disjoint and are all in $S_1$. With the specified operations, the only further sets you can form from these are unions of combinations of these, and there are $2^4 = 16$ combinations. So $S$ will have exactly $16$ elements if the above four sets are all nonempty, otherwise $S$ will have fewer than $16$ elements.

Comment: Correction: all in $S_2$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $S$ is contained in $\sigma(A, B)$ (the [$\sigma-algebra$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#%CF%83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets) generated by {A, B} ⊆ $P(M)$).
As |$\sigma(A_1, ..., A_k)$| $\leq$ |$P(P(1, ..., k))$| $ = 2^{2^k} $ (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433920/cardinality-of-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-finite-collections-of-sets) for details), we conclude that
|$S$| $\leq$ |$\sigma(A, B)$| $\leq 16$.

Now take $M = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $A = \{1, 2\}$, and $B = \{2, 3\}$.
Can you see why |$S$|$ = 16$ in this case?